# Opening a book on the left below parts

Tags: page-breaking, koma-script, scrbook, emptypage

I am writing a small cook book with scrbook and want the recipes to be set as follows:

```
----------  ---------
| Recipe |  | Image |
|        |  |       |
|        |  |       |
----------  ---------
```

This is simple enough when there is no structuring. But once I add chapter/parts, I have a problem with the titlepages. What I want is the following:

```
----------  ---------
|        |  | Title |
|        |  |       |
|        |  |       |
----------  ---------
----------  ---------
| Recipe |  | Image |
|        |  |       |
|        |  |       |
----------  ---------
```

But with open=left, I get:

```
----------  ---------
|  Title |  |       |
|        |  |       |
|        |  |       |
----------  ---------
----------  ---------
| Recipe |  | Image |
|        |  |       |
|        |  |       |
----------  ---------
```

and with open=right, I get:

```
----------  ---------
|        |  | Title |
|        |  |       |
|        |  |       |
----------  ---------
----------  ---------
|        |  | Recipe|
|        |  |       |
|        |  |       |
----------  ---------

----------  ---------
| Image  |  |  ...  |
|        |  |       |
|        |  |       |
----------  ---------
```

So what options do I have to implement the intended layout without changing titlepages, toc etc. ?

Comment: That depends on the actual code used. We don't know what you have done so far.

Comment: Hint: do not use the titlepage environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\part{\KOMAoptions{open=right}}{}{\PatchFailed}
\renewcommand\partheademptypage{\KOMAoptions{open=left}}
\BeforeTOCHead{\KOMAoptions{open=right}}
\AfterStartingTOC{\KOMAoptions{open=left}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First Part}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\Blindtext
\part{SecondPart}
\chapter{Another Chapter}
\Blindtext[7]
\chapter{Next Chapter}
\Blindtext[6]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: perfect! thanks! Do you mind to explain the magic?

Comment: `\partheademptypage` by default inserts an empty page after the part heading if a `scrbook`/`scrreprt` document is twosided and uses `option=right`.  You do not want this empty page. So this command can be redefined. In the code above it is used to switch to `open=left`. The lines with `\BeforeTOCHead` and `\AfterStartingTOC` are not really needed if the ToC (and LoF/LoT) are set before the first `\part`.